# Active Menu Item background remove wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am working on a site hobbinternational.com. There is a grey background which appears on the active menu item of the current page (Home). I want to remove the grey background of the active menu item. I only want the grey background when I hover on all the menu items. Thats it. Can anyone help me out? (I am using Wordpress, theme - Moody by Theme Move)

Answer (score 0):

Add below CSS

```
.menu--primary .menu__container > li.current-menu-item > a {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: .menu--primary .menu__container > li.current-menu-item > a {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS into your theme style.css file

```css
.menu--primary .menu__container > li > a:hover, .menu--primary .menu__container > li.current-menu-item > a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: ```background-color: transparent !important;```
try this

Comment: .menu--primary .menu__container > li.current-menu-item > a {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}